# Set Row of ImageViews in LinearLayout to be Square based on Screen Dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build basically a horizontal LinearLayout with 9 ImageViews where they are separated into 2 groups: one of two Images and the other with 7. I want each ImageView to be square and dynamic so their sizes adjust properly for different screens.

I've checked around StackOverflow, but I haven't found a solution to this. Attached is a rough image of what I'm trying to make. Thanks!

[Rough Example](http://imgur.com/a/E8V8A)